# Use a closure inside a thread

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a closure in a thread but after 2 hours of trying I can't seem to find how. Here's the file `discord_async.rs`:

```
use discord::*;
use discord::model::Event;
use std::sync::Arc;
use shared_mutex::SharedMutex;
use std::thread;

pub struct DiscordAsync {
    client: Arc<SharedMutex<Discord>>
}

impl DiscordAsync {
    pub fn new(bot_token: &str) -> DiscordAsync {
        let client = Arc::new(SharedMutex::new(Discord::from_bot_token(bot_token).unwrap()));
        DiscordAsync {
            client: client
        }
    }

    pub fn start<F>(&self, mut event_handle: F) -> () where F: FnMut(Arc<Event>, Arc<SharedMutex<Discord>>) + Send + 'static {
        let (mut connection, _) = self.client.read().unwrap().connect().unwrap();
        let event_handle = Arc::new(SharedMutex::new(event_handle));

        loop {
            let event = Arc::new(connection.recv_event().unwrap());
            let event_handle = event_handle.read().unwrap();

            // Start a thread so we don't block shit
            thread::spawn(move || {

                // Match event to actions we want to handle
                event_handle(event.clone(), self.client);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like this in `main.rs`:

```
extern crate colored;
extern crate discord;
extern crate shared_mutex;

mod discord_async;

use std::thread;
use colored::*;
use discord::*;
use discord::model::{Event, Channel, ServerId};
use discord_async::DiscordAsync;

fn main() {
    // Server info
    let bot_token = "...";
    let server_id = ServerId(12345);

    let dis_async = DiscordAsync::new(bot_token);
    dis_async.start(|event, _| {
        println!("{:?}", event);
    });
}
```

Compiler message:

```
   Compiling bottest1 v0.1.0 (file:///home/kindlyfire/Documents/dev/rust/bottest1)
error[E0477]: the type `[closure@src/discord_async.rs:29:18: 33:5 event_handle:shared_mutex::SharedMutexReadGuard<'_, F>, event:std::sync::Arc<discord::model::Event>, self:&discord_async::DiscordAsync]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/discord_async.rs:29:4
   |
29 |            thread::spawn(move || {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: type must outlive the static lifetime
```

And my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "bottest1"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["kindlyfire"]

[dependencies]
discord = "0.7.0"
colored = "1.4"
shared-mutex = "0.2"
```

I've looked at a lot of different ways to do this, including on SO, but I can't find any that work.

Comment: *And it doesn't work* => I just misplaced my mind-reading crystal ball, could you be slightly more explicit... such as including any compiler error? Please produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added the compiler error message and my `Cargo.toml`.

Answer (score 1):

You lock the mutex and then try to move the locked object into the thread. That's the wrong way around. You need to clone the `Arc` and move that into the thread.

**Edit:** I haven't tested this, but something like this should work:

```
pub fn start<F>(&self, mut event_handle: F) -> ()
    where F: FnMut(Arc<Event>, Arc<SharedMutex<Discord>>) + Send + 'static
{
    let (mut connection, _) = self.client.read().unwrap().connect().unwrap();
    let event_handle = Arc::new(SharedMutex::new(event_handle));

    loop {
        let event = Arc::new(connection.recv_event().unwrap());
        let event_handle = event_handle.clone();
        let client = self.client.clone();

        // Start a thread so we don't block shit
        thread::spawn(move || {

            // Match event to actions we want to handle
            event_handle.read().unwrap()(event, client);
        });
    }
}
```

Note that we create clones of the `Arc`s outside the lambda, and then use them inside. Except for `event`, which we don't clone, because we're fine with moving the one pointer we have. This moves the clones into the lambda. You could probably get rid of the `Arc` around `Event`, though. You don't have any other pointers to it, don't need to keep it alive, and it has to be `Send` anyway (I think `&T` is only `Sync` if `T` is `Send`).

If this doesn't work, please update with the new compiler error.

As a side note on terminology, a "handle" is an object that refers to some resource. A function that deals with events is a "handle**r**".

Comment: Could you provide me with the actual fixed code ? After making multiple edits that I think should do what you said I can't get it working. I just started working with Rust too, 2 days ago, so it's rather new.

Comment: It now results on a `cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable` on `event_handle.read().unwrap()`, even if I add `mut` after every `let` in the function.